# New contact besides Google Contact

Tags: contacts

1. Every-time I try to add a new contact, my Nexus S force me to put the contact under "Google contact from [my address]@gmail.com". Is there any way to change this? As I am concern on privacy. I do not want to let Google server to have every of my contacts.
2. After adding new contact, I have to go to "Display options". Under [my address]@gmail.com, there is a no name group (The first group with name is System Group:My Contacts). Is there any way I can assign name to the no name group?

Comment: You don't get the "Phone only, unsynced" option when you hit add? I thought that was in the standard Gingerbread contacts app.

Comment: No. I don't get the option. Can you show me the screen shoot? Also, where I can hit add? I can only hit Menu -> New Contact -> (Fill in the form) -> Done button.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I meant "New Contact", not add. I assumed it said add because of the `+` sign on the button but I never read the text very carefully...Anyhow, when I hit "New Contact" I get a little menu that has my gmail accounts listed and then "Phone only, unsynced" at the bottom so that I can choose where to put it. I would have thought you'd at least get the choice to put the contact on your phone even if you only have one account set up, but it sounds like that's not the case :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the option to add them unsynced.  Like this:
[image]

Comment: Weird. I do not get this window. Does it pop up automatically once you click on "New Contant"?

Comment: Yes.  I go to Contacts and hit Menu -> New Contact and it pops up.  Could it be because you've only set up one account?

Comment: If I go to Settings -> Accounts & sync, I have account for Google, Twitter and Yahoo. When I click on "Add account" button at the bottom, I do not see something called "Phone".

Comment: If I understand Android correctly, those “unsynced” choices are particular accounts. Can you tell us what *type* of accounts they are, or what application provides them, even if you can't tell us their specific names?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, contacts are always filed under some account. Presumably the design intent is that contacts are usually stored somewhere else, in some reliable storage, in case you lose the data on your phone.

I'm not in a position to try this myself, but here's a possible way to get an “unsynced” account: Install the free “[The Missing Sync for Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.markspace.missingsync&feature=search_result)” app. This app is intended to sync contacts directly with your desktop, and the desktop half is a paid app, but the phone side can be installed for free, and if you never sync it the data will stay on your phone.

The Missing Sync app will generate an account on your phone called “MissingSync” (which will be labeled “unsynced” even though it actually is synced via the Missing Sync app), which you can add contacts under.